# Visual Studio Python Debug - Input() function error

Tags: python, debug, visual-studio-2019

I'm having an issue getting the debug output window to accept input() function from my python code. 
I've tried reading stackoverflow tips but they are generally for Visual Studio Code and not Visual Studio 2019 IDE.

My error message comes from using: 
input()

Then I hit debug start (F5) 
this gives error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'readline'

How can I get the debugger to accept this?

Comment: This is more a programming question so should be asked on our sister site [SO]. In the meantime, have you tried looking at your `NoneType` object? I think that is where your problem lies.

Comment: ok. thanks. I think my code should return something. I'm not sure I understand the NoneType object compeletely but, isn't the debugger returning NoneType if your code doesn't return anything. Like None value?